# An abelian category such that all objects are injective

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

The problem is 'Let C be an abelian category such that all objects in C are injective. Prove that all abjects are projective.'
If C has enough projectives, then the 'Ext' functor can be defined. Thus the problem is trivial as $Ext^{n}(M,N)=0$ for all objects M and N. But how can I prove that without the property 'enough projectives'?

Comment: Both of these conditions are equivalent to every short exact sequence splitting ("semisimplicity"), with no appeal to the Ext functor.

Comment: In any case, you can use Yoneda Ext (defined in terms of extensions), which amounts to the same thing.